# SQL - Get most recent records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `table`:

```
Id   |   Name   |   Date
-----+----------+-----------------------
1    | name1    | 2021-02-10 13:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
1    | name2    | 2021-02-10 05:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
1    | name3    | 2021-02-09 14:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
2    | name4    | 2021-01-02 03:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
2    | name5    | 2021-01-07 11:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
2    | name6    | 2021-01-07 08:00:00.000
```

I need to get the records with the latest `Date` (Only the date without considering the time) for each `Id` group:

```
Id   |   Name   |   Date
-----+----------+-----------------------
1    | name1    | 2021-02-10 13:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
1    | name2    | 2021-02-10 05:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
2    | name5    | 2021-01-07 11:00:00.000
-----+----------+-----------------------
2    | name6    | 2021-01-07 08:00:00.000
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `RANK()`:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, T.DATE
FROM (SELECT t.*
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, DATE) DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM T
     ) T
WHERE T.SEQNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T.ID,T.NAME,T.DATE FROM
  (
     SELECT ID,NAME,DATE,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC)AS XCOL
       FROM YOUR_TABLE
  )T WHERE T.XCOL=1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with a minimal reproducible example.

The `RANK()` function is a window function that could be used to calculate a rank for each row within a partition of a result set.

The same rank is assigned to the rows in a partition which have the same values.

By the way, a poor selection for column names.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT, [name] VARCHAR(30), [Date] DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, [name], [Date]) VALUES
(1,'name1','2021-02-10 13:00:00.000'),
(1,'name2','2021-02-10 05:00:00.000'),
(1,'name3','2021-02-09 14:00:00.000'),
(2,'name4','2021-01-02 03:00:00.000'),
(2,'name5','2021-01-07 11:00:00.000'),
(2,'name6','2021-01-07 08:00:00.000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT tbl.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
             , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE) DESC) AS seq
      FROM @tbl AS t
     ) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.seq = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+-------------------------+-----+
| ID | name  |          Date           | seq |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-----+
|  1 | name1 | 2021-02-10 13:00:00.000 |   1 |
|  1 | name2 | 2021-02-10 05:00:00.000 |   1 |
|  2 | name5 | 2021-01-07 11:00:00.000 |   1 |
|  2 | name6 | 2021-01-07 08:00:00.000 |   1 |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-----+
```